# Android recyclerview and fragment : put my data fetch into my recycler view

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I'm stuck with this since 1 week and I can't get why my data fetch are not displayed into my cardAdaptater. I can see they are fetched well but I can't acces to them after it in the fragment

Here is my HomePageFragment where data should be displayed

```
class HomePage {
    class HomeFragment : Fragment(), HeaderScrollBarAdapter.ItemClickListener {

        private var cardAdapter: HomeCardItemAdapter? = null
        private val url = "https://kolibrii-prod.herokuapp.com/tutorial"
        private var listTuto = ArrayList<Model.Tuto>()

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)



        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            getData()         



            // Set up card recycler view
            val cardRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.menuheaderscrollbar2)
            val verticalLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            cardRecyclerView.layoutManager = verticalLayoutManager
            cardRecyclerView.adapter = cardAdapter
            Log.d("tutorender",listTuto.toString())
        }

        // Function to fetch Tutorial data
        private fun getData() {

            val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(url,
                Response.Listener<JSONArray> { response ->
                    for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
                        try {
                            val jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i)
                            val jsonTitle = jsonObject.getString("title")
                            val jsonDuration = jsonObject.getString("duration")
                            val jsonPrice = jsonObject.getString("price")
                            val jsonLevel = "Facile"
                            val jsonImg = (R.drawable.testons)
                            val jsonId = jsonObject.getInt("id")
                            val tutoEntrie = Model.Tuto(jsonTitle,jsonDuration,jsonPrice,jsonLevel, jsonImg, jsonId)
                            listTuto.add(tutoEntrie)
                        }
                        catch (e: JSONException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }

                    }

                    cardAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    Log.d("tuto", listTuto.toString())
                }, Response.ErrorListener { Log.e("Volley", "Volley error on tutorial") })
            val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my cardAdapter.kit :

```
class HomeCardItemAdapter // data is passed into the constructor
internal constructor(
    context: FragmentActivity?,
    private val tutos: ArrayList<Model.Tuto>
   //private val mCatePicture: List<Int>
)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeCardItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private val mInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var mClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null


    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_card_items, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    // binds the data to the view and textview in each row
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentTuto = tutos.get(position)
     //   val catePicture= mCatePicture[position]
        holder.titleTextView.text = currentTuto.title
        holder.timeTextView.text = currentTuto.duration
        holder.priceTextView.text = currentTuto.price
       holder.levelTextView.text = currentTuto.level
        //holder.categoryImageView.setImageResource(catePicture)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.cardImageView.clipToOutline = true
        }
    }

    // total number of rows
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return tutos.size
        }

    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    inner class ViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {
        internal var cardImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_img_bg)
        internal var titleTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title)
        internal var priceTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_price)
        internal var timeTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_time)
        internal var levelTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_level)
        internal var categoryImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_theme_icon)


}
```

Thank you in advance to the people who could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize the adapter, it's always null and due to the the safe operator (?) those calls are never actually invoked.

```
// Function to fetch Tutorial data
private fun getData() {
   val jsonArrayRequest = JsonArrayRequest(url,
   Response.Listener<JSONArray> { response ->
   for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
      try {
         val jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i)
         val jsonTitle = jsonObject.getString("title")
         val jsonDuration = jsonObject.getString("duration")
         val jsonPrice = jsonObject.getString("price")
         val jsonLevel = "Facile"
         val jsonImg = (R.drawable.testons)
         val jsonId = jsonObject.getInt("id")
         val tutoEntrie = Model.Tuto(jsonTitle,jsonDuration,jsonPrice,jsonLevel, jsonImg, jsonId)
         listTuto.add(tutoEntrie)
      } catch (e: JSONException) {
         e.printStackTrace()
      }

    }

    // THIS HERE IS NEVER ACTUALLY CALLED AS THE ADAPTER IS ALWAYS NULL
    cardAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

    Log.d("tuto", listTuto.toString())
    }, Response.ErrorListener { Log.e("Volley", "Volley error on tutorial") })
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest)
    } 
}
```

add this before notifyDataSetChanged

```
cardAdapter = HomeCardItemAdapter(this, listTuto)
// attach adapter
findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.menuheaderscrollbar2).adapter = cardAdapter
cardAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged() // this might not be necessary
```

EDIT: added further explanation:

Your call to getData() is prior to configuring your recyclerview and attaching the adapter. Therefore you should modify the `onViewCreated()` as followed.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

     // Set up card recycler view
     val cardRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.menuheaderscrollbar2)
     val verticalLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
     cardRecyclerView.layoutManager = verticalLayoutManager

     // now that recyclerview is ready
     getData()         
}
```

Comment: I did, I receive this in Logcat error :
   No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: @ClémentRousseau I've updated the answer, the adapter is created after the getData() is finished so no adapter is attached when trying to, also the adapter should be created and attached when data are ready.

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as the correct one, so that the issue closes.